# ASP.NET Core gateway ocelot API doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, microservices

I'm creating a project with microservices and now I want to be able to test the API gateway that I created as an orchestrator with ocelot, but I can't test it through the browser, the API can't access it, can someone help?

ocelot.json:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    // Billing.API
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/Billing",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "billingapi",
          "Port": "80"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/Billing",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the project and in the browser URL I pass `/api/v1/Billing`

as I passed the `DownstreamPathTemplate` property.
Nothing is returned to me.

Comment: Are you sure hostname "billingapi" exists? Also post your error message

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first try general template and see if it works:

```
{
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{everything}",
    "DownstreamScheme": "http",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
                "Host": "billingapi",
                "Port": 80,
            }
        ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/billingapi/{everything}",
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post" ]
}
```

From the Ocelot documentation about Downstream:

```
The DownstreamPathTemplate, DownstreamScheme and DownstreamHostAndPorts define the URL that a request will be forwarded to.
```

And for the Upstream:

```
The UpstreamPathTemplate is the URL that Ocelot will use to identify which DownstreamPathTemplate to use for a given request.
```

Comment: requestId: 0HM69A4IV0LEC:00000007, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: ConnectionToDownstreamServiceError Message: Error connecting to downstream service, exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 
This host is not known. (billingapi:80)

Comment: I updated my answer to be more general. But now in the url you have to add billingapi/api/v1/endpointname

Answer (score 0):

You should pass UpstreamPathTemplate URL on the browser to route billing API. In your case, the request **HTTP://<gateway.address>/Billings** will be routed to **HTTP://billingapi/api/v1/Billing**.